# Access matplotlib objects of scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a matplotlib 2.0.0 scatter plot with few points, I want to annotate some of the points without overlapping other points. For the annotation, I use [adjustText](https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText) which takes an optional list of matplotlib objects (with the .get_window_extent() method) to avoid. But I could not yet find out how to get those objects for the points in the scatter plot.

How can I get a list of (point) objects having `.get_window_extent()` from the scatter plot?

Consider for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
x,y = [1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,6,8,10]
scatter = plt.scatter(x,y)
annotations = []
for x_i, y_i in zip(x[:-3],y[:-3]):
    annotations.append(plt.text(x_i,y_i, 'foobar'))
adjust_text(annotations, add_objects=scatter)
```

Using `add_objects=`

- `scatter` throws a `TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable`
- `scatter.get_paths()` throws a `AttributeError: 'Path' object has no attribute 'get_window_extent'`

Comment: Looks like `scatter.get_children()` is the solution!

Comment: Actually, `scatter.get_children()` returns an empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you simply missed the additional arguments in `adjust_text`. You may supply the `x` and `y` coordinates of the points directly to the function:

```
adjust_text(annotations,x=x,y=y)
```

Full example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from adjustText import adjust_text
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 3,2
x,y = [1,2,3,4,5],[2,4,2,8,10]
scatter = plt.scatter(x,y)
annotations = []
for x_i, y_i in zip(x,y):
    annotations.append(plt.text(x_i,y_i, 'foobar {},{}'.format(x_i,y_i)))
adjust_text(annotations,x=x,y=y)

plt.show()
```

[image]